# Crystal Report Alignment issue after printing

Tags: crystal-reports

By user define size option page setup was done.
Basically, page generate Account statement when their is 0 transaction the report on printing fix at center of page.
How to over come this issue? I want to fix table for all the case either their is transaction or not.

Comment: can you show image how exactly you need?

Comment: I've pdf which show accurate result but on print its alignment disturb